# Why code work in selenium chrome driver if i put break on my code but receive error if removed?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Error Screenshot]

I run my test code in debug mode. I put break on line "**issuetab.Click()**" before I continue the debug. It works ok. But later I try to remove the break and rerun I receive error as per my screenshot image. Not sure what is the cause of error and how to solve it. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you use the explicit wait and click on the element once it's present. Seems to be other element is overlapping the current element, you can use javascript click instead of general click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved as below:

```
    Thread.Sleep(4000);

    /*Create and initilaize object*/

    IWebElement issuetab = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#tab-header ul li:nth-child(7) a")); //select issue tab        

    Actions actions_issuetab = new Actions(driver);
    actions_issuetab.MoveToElement(issuetab).Click().Perform(); //click the tab
```